# Note-taking Software

Tags: note-taking

While working on a non-fiction book, I need to take hundreds of random notes. I kinda like sticky-note-like approach, but, say, Google Keep becomes too messy after a while. Software like Scrivener are too fiction-book-author oriented (chapter-character-scene based). Microsoft OneNote and the like is too clumsy for too many notes.

(Not that I am hopeful, but) Is there an application (Windows or web-based), which primarily looks/functions like Jupyter Notebook (that each cell is a note), where each cell can be tagged (not an absolute must, but useful), where we can insert images (not an absolute must, but useful), etc.?

Comment: Why not use one, or more, Jupyter Notebooks?

Answer (score 2):

If you want something similar to a jupyter style notebook, where a cell = one bulletpoint, you should strongly consider either [dynalist.io](https://dynalist.io/) or [workflowy](https://workflowy.com/)

Answer (score 1):

What about Evernote? (Not free unfortunately.)

The tagging capability is fantastic. You can take pictures of your handwritten notes and it will make the text of the note searchable. Search is fast. Type in (or speak) a quick note from your smartphone. On and on ...

The thought unit of Evernote is a "note" so the parallel with how you like to work is there also.